# Arrows next to Launcher Icons in Unity 2D

Tags: 12.04, launcher, icons, unity-2d

What do the tiny white arrows next to the icons in the Unity 2D launcher mean? Sometimes there is one, often more. Do they indicate the number of windows of that application that are open?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, white arrow mean you have window opened in current workspace, the transparent with white border mean the window opened in other workspace.

Arrow number indicate how much window are open.